# Will this achieve linear movement of a closed container?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Can I create a device that moves in one direction with a design like Figure 1? I suspect that the forces cancel each other by the recirculation. It is a simple exercise of action and reaction, but I can not figure out the math to explain.

Maybe my problem is of type [XY problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

My intention is to create a device that produces movement from a **closed container**, something like a black box. (which would be added energy)

Figure 1.

[image]

Comment: Is this in a closed container? I'm confused what setup you're trying to communicate.

Comment: yes, is a closed container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the device will not work.  The design, if it worked, would violate the [conservation of momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum#Conservation).  If the [center of mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass) of any isolated system of objects is initially at rest, the center of mass won't change location for any reason.  So if the device doesn't interact with anything outside of itself, the only way for the device to move forward would be if something was expelled out of the back of the device.